# C basics, const unsigned char* to integer or bool

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get integer or bool from database result this way:

```
bool tblexist = false;
int t_exists = 0;    

tblexist = (bool)sqlite3_column_text(chkStmt, 1);
t_exists = atoi(sqlite3_column_text(chkStmt, 1));
```

... but no one works.
Expected value from sqlite3_column_text(chkStmt, 1) is always 0 or 1.
But I get error message:

> invalid conversion from ‘const unsigned char*’ to ‘const char*’
>     initializing argument 1 of ‘int atoi(const char*)’
>     ||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|

How to solve this and get integer or bool on elegant way?

Comment: Changed tag from C to C++, as `bool` and `false` are C++ specific.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: And how about using `atoi`? C++? :)

Comment: @Als Not very "C++"-ish, but still possible to use. :)

Comment: By adding stdbool.h bool and false incorporates well in plain C.

Comment: Why not use `sqlite3_column_int` ?

Comment: Another, excellent idea, never heard about before! Works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line, trying to convert to `bool` will always return `true`, as a string pointer will always be "true" if it's not NULL. If you want to use this there are a couple of ways to handle this:

```
// 1. Dereference pointer to get first character in string
tblexist = (*sqlite3_column_text(chkStmt, 1) != '0');

// 2. Using string comparison
tblexist = (strcmp(sqlite3_column_text(chkStmt, 1), "0") != 0);
```

For the second, try this instead:

```
t_exists = atoi((const char *) sqlite3_column_text(chkStmt, 1));
```

This is because `sqlite3_column_text` returns the type `const unsigned char *` but `atoi` wants `const char *`.

Comment: Finally get it with dereferencing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

atoi or similar conversion would be expensive to use.

```
const unsigned char _TRUE = '1';
const unsigned char* dbDATA = sqlite3_column_text(chkStmt, 1);
bool exists = (_TRUE == dbDATA[0]); //i assume you are expecting "0" or "1" from DB
```

Comment: Expensive compared to a database access?

Comment: Here is segfault bool bool exists = (_TRUE == dbDATA[0]);

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the columns are indexed beginning with zero, so unless the query requested two (or more) columns, `sqlite3_column_text(..., 1)` returns the second column.

Secondly, the function returns a pointer to a character string, so you have to dereference the value from the pointer, and convert the string there:

```
const char *data = sqlite3_column_text(chkStmt, 0);
int val = atoi (data);   // for ascii representation of a number
```

Comment: Yes, I need value from second column. Still have error 'invalid conversion from ‘const unsigned char*’ to ‘const char*’' at first line of your example.